# How to fetch db table values using mysql query in magento 2. Magento 2 use sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

I'm new in Magento.

CustomModule\Database\Controller\Page\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace CustomModule\Database\Controller\Page;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

CustomModule\Database\Block\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace CustomModule\Database\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Index extends Template
{
 
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    public $resourceConnection;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
 
    /**
     * Get Table name using direct query
     */
    public function getTablename($tableName)
    {
        /* Create Connection */
        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName   = $connection->getTableName($tableName);
        return $tableName;
    }
}
```

CustomModule\Database\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml

```
<?php
$tableName = $this->getTableName('sales_invoice_item');
$query = 'SELECT name,sku,price,qty FROM' . $tableName;
/**
 * Execute the query and store the results in $results variable
 */
$results = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->fetchCol($query);
echo "<pre>";print_r($results);
?>
```

Showing an error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: CustomModule\Database\Block\Index

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: CustomModule\Database\Block\Index
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('CustomModule\Dat...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('CustomModule\Dat...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\BlockFactory.php:46]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('CustomModule\Dat...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php:272]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('CustomModule\Dat...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php:252]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('CustomModule\Dat...', 'index', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php:229]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure#0000000006b3bc800000000037a2235d#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#0000000006b3b9d10000000037a2235d#, 'index') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php:134]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000006b3b33b0000000037a2235d#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#0000000006b3bc8d0000000037a2235d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool.php:81]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000006b3b33b0000000037a2235d#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#0000000006b3bc8d0000000037a2235d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:352]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('generateElements', array()) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('generateElements', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...', 'core-session-dep...', 'customer-session...', 'catalog-session-...', 'persistent-sessi...', 'checkout-session...', 'tax-session-depe...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:91]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php:129]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Builder.php:55]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php:65]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php:224]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php:237]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor.php:37]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor->publicBuild() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php:242]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbde0000000037a2235d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbde0000000037a2235d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbde0000000037a2235d#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbde0000000037a2235d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbde0000000037a2235d#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:130]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbde0000000037a2235d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:120]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000006b3bbd70000000037a2235d#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, more details or clarify of problem, improve content quality, improve text arragement, improve code formatting, include the current result, include the expected result


.

See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from the database table by MySQL query with below code:

```
protected $_resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
}

public function execute()
{
    // get connection
    $connection     = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    // table name
    $tableName = $this->_resource->getTableName('your table name');
    // Query
    $select_sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
    // fetch result
    $results = $connection->fetchAll($select_sql);
    // print result
    print_r($results);
}
```

Comment: @ZubairShaikh Please accept if this answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: You don't.
Magento 2 offers you Collections and Factories to access Database resources, not requiring you do write any plain SQL queries like any modern framework should.
You can inject CollectionFactory classes into your Classes constructor like this:

```
   /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory */
   private $productCollectionFactory;

   public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory) {
      $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
   }
```

Like this you can get object representations of any invoice, order, product, product categories and many more.
However, if you really need to directly run SQL, Amit Saini`s answer is the way to go.
I found [this source](https://meetanshi.com/blog/run-direct-sql-query-in-magento-2/) on that.

Comment: Thank you @L. Gerhardt  for guiding me.